# Pycharm doesn't recognize any python interpreters

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, interpreter

I have downloaded a PyCharm 2021.3 on Windows 10, and when I want to configure a python interpreter for the project, I don't have any options except . When I try to do it with the menu ctrl+Al+s python via python interpreter, I also see no available options.  When I run code, it returns the first occurred exception, ModuleNotFoundError. I have python version 3.9.9 and conda installed, and they both are working perfectly fine via command prompt and Jupyter Notebook.
That's how it looks:
[no interpreter via python interpreter menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z7Y6.png)

[no interpreter in edit configurations window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWVO5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the following worked:

1. Delete folders with the current project in the PycharmProjects directory.
2. Create a new project, clone to this new project my project from git.

Then I had an option to edit configurations and select python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains has really good docomentation in terms of using their software. Check out this official guide on how to setup a Conda interpreter
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the options stated on the menu. I don't have gear with possible options in the python interpreter menu, as I've shown in the 1-st pic attached.